# How to get the output column using a sql query basis the logic

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
Date              id    output     
11/26/2018 12:24   A    1    
12/10/2018 23:34   A    0    
12/11/2018 16:03   A    0   
12/11/2018 16:34   A    0    
12/12/2018 9:58    A    0    
12/13/2018 9:27    A    1    
12/6/2018 8:48     B    1    
12/26/2018 8:49    B    1
```

I'm trying to create a new column which has a value of 1 or 0 basis the logic.

1. For each unique value of id if the difference of the max value of date and min value of the date is > 15 days - output is 1 else 0
2. else if the date difference is < 15 days and id has a count(id) > 1 - output is 0 else 1
3. last row for each unique id - output should be always 1

I'm trying to implement the logic in a SQL query to get the output column to be 1 or 0 basis the logic. Can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

This should handle your conditions:

```
select t.*,
       ( (seqnum = 1) or
         (max_date > min_date + interval '15 day')
       )::int as flag
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum,
             max(date) over (partition by id) as max_date,
             min(date) over (partition by id) as min_date
      from t
     ) t;
```

Your second condition is redundant with the last condition.  If the count is 1, then the record is the last record.

Comment: and the count in 2)?

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . The condition is redundant, as the answer states.

Answer (score 0):

This query should do:

```
with
x as (
  select
    id,
    min(date) as mind,
    max(date) as maxd,
    count(*) as cnt
  from my_table
  group by id
),
select
  t.date, 
  t.id,
  case
    when t.date = x.maxd then 1 
    when datediff('day', x.mind, x.maxd) > 15 then 1
    when x.cnt <= 1 then 1
    else 0 end as output
from my_table t
join x on x.id = t.id
```